# IntelliJ delete files from project but from disk

Tags: intellij-idea

When I delete a file (either a class, a library or anything) from a project in IntelliJ , the file will also be deleted from the disk physically! Is there any way to avoid this? I may still need the file, but I just don't want it in this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy it away from the place on the disc manually before deleting it.

Your IDE uses different build systems (e.G. maven, ant, etc...) and cannot rely on all of them to correctly "ignore" stuff you have marked as deleted.

I usually have a "misc" project in my IDE where I move stuff like what you described.

The same goes for all IDEs, be it IntelliJ, Netbeans or Eclipse. The representation in your project should always be the same as on your disk.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, but I stated the wrong IDE, it should be IntelliJ.

Comment: @WeixiangGuan I have edited the answer. Its true for all IDEs, really.

Comment: Thanks! As I remember Visual Studio seems also to delete the physical file, but deleting libraries will not delete also the dll! However this is something I should be careful about.